# Spark job failing on jackson dependencies

Tags: apache-spark, jackson

I have spark job that is failing after the upgrade of the cdh from `5.5.4` which had `spark 1.5.0 to cdh 5.13.0` which has `spark 1.6.0`

The job is running with the new spark dependencies but i see strange behavior for one spark job that:

1) sometimes it's oozie launcher marked as success and other as killed,

2) also for the spark job itself i see that is failing on the jackson databind.

> 2018-01-05 19:07:17,672 [Driver] ERROR
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster - User class threw
>   exception: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack Exception
>   Details:   Location:
>       org/apache/spark/metrics/sink/MetricsServlet.(Ljava/util/Properties;Lcom/codahale/metrics/MetricRegistry;Lorg/apache/spark/SecurityManager;)V
>   @116: invokevirtual   Reason:
>       Type 'com/codahale/metrics/json/MetricsModule' (current frame, stack[2]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module'

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

The error you are getting is a **Java Bytecode Verification Error**.
This happens right before the class can be loaded onto the JVM by the classloader.
The purpose of this step is to ensure that the code didn't come from a malicious compiler, but indeed follows the Java language rules.

Read more about it here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/security-136118.html

Now, to address your problem. This error is also thrown when your code finds different jars/classes at runtime than the ones which were used during compile time.

The MetricServlet class in the spark-core lib tries to instantiate an object of type MetricsModule which is packaged inside the metrics-json jar.
Then it tries to register this object (within it's 'ObjectMapper') as a generic Module object.
Note: MetricsModule extends from the Module class of jackson-databind jar.
So, in simple terms, an object of type MetricsModule is being type-casted to parent class Module.

**However, the MetricsModule class in your environment is not loaded from the metrics-json Jar, but some other foreign Jar or third party library, where it extended a different Module parent class**.
**This Jar must have been compiled using some.other.package.Module class rather than the original com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module from jackson-databind.**

E.g. Uber JAR for CosmosDB connector for Spark packages both MetricsModule and Module class. But the latter is packaged under "cosmosdb_connector_shaded.jackson.databind.Module" giving the exact same error -

> "Type 'com/codahale/metrics/json/MetricsModule' (current frame,
>   stack[2]) is not assignable to
>   'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module'"

To resolve this class conflict you need to find the JAR which actually loaded MetricsModule class. Use **-verbose:class** JVM option with your Spark Driver JVM to track this.

Comment: Wonderful tip. In my case, the version being loaded at runtime came from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.dropwizard.metrics/metrics-json; wouldn't have been able to pinpoint that dependency without the -verbose:class option.

Comment: Thanks for the reasoning. But what is the solution here to fix this conflict?

Answer (score 0):

@sg1 explanation is accurate. For me, I fixed this error by adding the jars as part of `spark.driver.extraClassPath` instead of copying them in `jars/` directory of spark. You can also try shading the particular dependency such as Jackson in your uber jar.

Answer (score 0):

Since Spark already shipped the metrics-json jar, we can mark the scope as provided, which will resolve the conflicts.

```xml
    <!-- Metrics -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
      <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
      <version>${metrics.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
      <artifactId>metrics-json</artifactId>
      <version>${metrics.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```